# I have tried all these things but it is stating it cannot find entity id

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have tried all these things but it is stating it cannot find entity id
and I get following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService': Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo': Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.example.demo.repositories.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.demo.repositories.UserRepo.findOneByEmailIdAndPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.demo.repositories.UserRepo.findOneByEmailIdAndPassword(jav`your text`a.lang.String,java.lang.String); No property 'id' found for type 'String'; Traversed path: User.email

UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class UserController {

        @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> loginEmployee(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto)
    {
        LoginMessage loginMessage=userService.loginUser(loginDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(loginMessage);
    }
}
```

UserService

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

String addUser(UserDto userDto);
LoginMessage loginUser(LoginDto loginDto);

}
```

UserServiceImplementation

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

@Override
public String addUser(UserDto userDto) {
    User user=new User(
    userDto.getId(),
    userDto.getName(),
    userDto.getEmail(),
    userDto.getPassword()
    );
    userRepo.save(user);
    return user.getName();
}

private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public LoginMessage loginUser(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    String msg="";
    User user1=userRepo.findByEmail(loginDto.getEmail());
    if(user1 !=null)
    {
        String password=loginDto.getPassword();
        String encodedPassword=user1.getPassword();
        Boolean isPwdRight=passwordEncoder.matches(password,encodedPassword);
        if(isPwdRight)
        {
            Optional<User>
      user=userRepo.findOneByEmailIdAndPassword(loginDto.getEmail(),encodedPassword);
            if(user.isPresent())
            {
                return new LoginMessage("Login Success", true);
            }
            else
            {
                return new LoginMessage("Login Failed", false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new LoginMessage("Password Not Match", false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new LoginMessage("Email not exist", false);
    }
}   
 }
```

UserRepository

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

Optional<User> findOneByEmailIdAndPassword(String email, String password);

User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `@Service` from `UserService` interface ?

Comment: You don't have a field called `emailId` only `email`. Rename your method to `findByEmailAndPassword`. Also it doesn't really add anything to retrieve the user (again) using the email and password. You already validated it.

Comment: I have tried removing @Service. And in userRepo method is defined by email only and not by emailid

Answer (score 1):

it seams the problem here is that query is wrongly build using spring data.

```
findOneByEmailIdAndPassword
```

this looks to be the problem from the error message. Maybe also add the User.java class to check if your query is well written